# Counting all pages updated

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-analytics, share, analytics, sharepiont

I need to count how many pages we have updated on our Sharepoint page. Our Sharepoint site contains around 15 000 pages. IS there a code or a tool I could use that would tell me which pages have been updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Audit Logs.

Try the below:

- [How to enable Audit functionality in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointthomas.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in.html)
- [View audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131)